# mysql connection to database not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I transfer my website from old server to new and I have follow error:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/dtutto/public_html/config.inc.php on line 541

at line 541 of config.inc.php i have

```
$cn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die("Cannot connect to DB" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Error accessing DB");
```

Where is problem? maybe a different php version?

Comment: A different century I'd say

Comment: PHP's error is quite clear :/

Comment: Well.. don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.